# Bind DataGridCell Foreground color to ViewModel Brush Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

I have a style trigger as follows.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ValidMatch">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValidMatch}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The style works fine. But when the color of any datagrid cell changes to Red then I would like to Bind the color to the `System.Windows.Media.Brush` `BrushProperty` in the viewmodel and say something like

```
if(Colors.Red.Equal(BrushProperty)) then do something.
```

Problem is when I have a setter property like

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" 
        Value="{Binding BrushProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True"}/>
```

included in the `DataGridCellStyle`, it doesn't apply the foreground color to red in the UI and never binds the color to the ViewModel. The ViewModel implements BindableBase. How do I bind the datagridcell color to a property in the viewmodel and do some comparison. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing like this,

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValidMatch}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding BrushProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Set your `BrushProperty` from `ViewModel`

Comment: I tried this private Brush _foreround;
  public Brush Foreground
  {
   get { return Brushes.Red; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _foreround, value); }
  }
But it dosent apply the red color to the datagridcell.

Comment: Have you checked your output window for binding errors ?